# Creating a long vector of strings in R

Tags: r, vector, paste

I have a very long column of names in a spreadsheet.
These names are essentially surnames separated by blanks from initials of the first/middle names.

Examples:

```
DUAN W  
GU B    
WHINSTON AB etc.
```

I need a vector like
`names <- c("DUAN W","GU B","WHINSTON AB")`

Of course, I can do all this pre-processing in the spreadsheet itself and then paste in R.
    But I was wondering if this could be done in R using,say, paste(). 
    Since I have to do this repeatedly, is there a way to avoid writing spreadsheet formulas each time?

Comment: If you have read it with read.table, `unlist(read.table('file.csv'))`

Comment: I'm not sure which part you are trying to automate. Are you trying to create a character vector or the code to generate a character vector?

Comment: Do you want to change 1 column dataframe to vector. If your dataframe is called `df`, you can just do `df[[1]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your workbook is `NAMES.xlsx`

```
library(tidyverse)
  # Read them in from the Excel file
readxl::read_excel("C:/temp/NAMES.xlsx") %>% 
   # Divide the single column in two.
  separate(NAMES, into = c("LAST.NAME", "FIRST.NAME"), sep = " ", extra = "merge") %>% 
   # First name goes before last name
  select(FIRST.NAME, LAST.NAME)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  FIRST.NAME LAST.NAME
  <chr>      <chr>    
1 W          DUAN     
2 B          GU       
3 AB         WHINSTON 
4 M          MOUSE    
5 S          MCDUCK   
6 PP         LEPEW
```